# AWS CodeDeploy to EC2 not updating modified date for files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

My deployment is putting the files on the server but all of the files have a modified time of 0 so Apache isn't hosting the updated files.

I added an AfterInstall script that is supposed to touch every file in the directory but it's not working for some reason. There is no error and if I run the script manually it works fine, just not during the deploy process.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Is there something simple I'm overlooking to make this work?

Touch script

```
#!/bin/bash
find /var/www/html/docs -type f -exec touch {} +
```

YML file

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /source/
    destination: /var/www/html/site/
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
permissions:
  - object: /var/www/html/site
    pattern: "**"
    owner: [redacted]
    group: [redacted]
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/after_install
      timeout: 10
      runas: [redacted]
```

Comment: Are you running the script as the "[redacted]" user?

Comment: Yes, everything is running as the same user that has permission to do the actions specified.